# Pygame grabbing console input when using framebuffer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, keyboard, background-process, framebuffer

I have a Raspberry Pi with a PiTFT module. I'm wanting to use Pygame to display information on the module using the framebuffer (without X). I have all the display stuff working but the problem is that pygame is grabbing the input from the keyboard so that I can't even change the terminal with alt 1-7.

This task is supposed to run in the background so this is not desired behavior. I can't find any way to disable it though. It looked like pygame.event.set_grab() might have been appropriate but did not help. Here is a cut-down version of my code which exhibits the same issue.

```
import os
import pygame
import time
from time import gmtime,strftime,localtime

class pytest :
screen = None

def __init__(self):
    os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
    try:
        pygame.display.init()
    except pygame.error:
        print 'Init failed.'

    size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    pygame.event.set_grab(0)
    pygame.font.init()
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 30)

def __del__(self):
    "Destructor to make sure pygame shuts down, etc."

def test(self):

    lightblue = (92, 92, 176)
    self.screen.fill(lightblue)
    tm=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",localtime())
    t=self.font.render(tm,1,(255,255,155))
    self.screen.blit(t,(240,00))
    pygame.display.update()

scope = pytest()
while 1:
  scope.test()
  pygame.event.pump()
  time.sleep(1)
```